Profinite completion of profinite groups
I was trying to prove that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ cannot be a galoisgroup for any extension.
My plan for this was to show that $\mathbb{R}$ is a divisible group and that every quotient of a divisible group further must be divisible. Now because $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is divisible and commutative we have that the profinite completion must be trivial.
Now to my question: is it enough to show that the profinite completion of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial to prove that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ cannot be a profinite group? If so, why? In the linked lecture notes I have read that a group is isomorphic to its profinite completion if and only if every subgroup with finite index is open. lecture notes on page 6.

Every non-trivial profinite group has a subgroup of finite index. The divisible group $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ obviously has no subgroup of finite index. Hence this group cannot be a Galois group. So you can replace your argument in the first part, without using the profinite completion. Of course it follows from this, that the profinite completion of $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ is trivial.

@DietrichBurde thank you very much, so generally speaking there may be a profinite group with trivial profinite completion? Also, is the fact, that every non-trivial profinite group has a subgroup of finite index trivial or is this nontrivial to proof?

In any compact group, open subgroups have finite index. This follows directly. And subgroups of profinite groups are open. For more details, see the slides here, for example.
